# Interactively debug with REPL

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to interactively debug with REPL.
I set a breakpoint in the code, for example this code on the println line

```
    var testVar : String = "test variable"

    println(testVar)
```

when the code blocks, I write in the console "repl" + return
the repl console appears

writing "testVar" (without quotes) I have back $R0: String = "test variable" , that is correct.
However, If I write a more complicated statement, like:

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("unused")

it returns:

Execution interrupted. Enter Swift code to recover and continue.

Enter LLDB commands to investigate (type :help for assistance.)

The strange thing is that I'm sure to have used this exact statement this moring and it worked (there is a post on the Apple Dev forum)
What is the reason of the Execution Interrupted error?

Thanks
Fabio

Answer (score 2):

NSUserDefaults is available in Foundation framework.

Therefore you need to import it to REPL

```
import Foundation
```

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten to say...The framework has been correctly imported with "import Foundation" before calling NSUserDefaults...